# Cannot get WCF web service working with Windows auth

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I've written my first WCF web service, which works great on my own local test webserver, however I'm getting an error when I deploy it to IIS.

Our IIS server uses integrated auth, and does *not* allow anonymous access.  From [what I've read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/03/23/preventing-anonymous-access.aspx), I need to set the security mode on the binding to `TransportCredentialOnly`.  The entire section in `web.config` is:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Website.TPMAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Website.TPM">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Website.TPMAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Website.TPM" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

However, when I load the web service in the browser, I get the error message:

```
Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.
```

Is there anything else I need to change or configure to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The `binding` attribute on the `endpoint` has to match the node in the `<bindings>` collection.  The following will work:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```